# What are good Windows anti-debug references?

Tags: windows, anti-debugging

What are good anti-debug references for Windows which help with manual unpacking, emulating, or sandboxing?

Comment: Its great that you wrote this Q&A, but asking for references is not considered constructive. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153220/why-is-asking-for-references-sources-to-study-specific-topics-considered-not-con even though it may be a self answered question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Peter Ferrie's [“Ultimate” Anti-Debugging Reference](http://pferrie.host22.com/papers/antidebug.pdf) (PDF, 147 pages) contains **many** anti-debugs, whether they're hardware or API based...
- Walied Assar's [blog](http://waleedassar.blogspot.com/) shows his researches, which are focused on finding new anti-debugs.

other (maybe redundant) resources:

- Nicolas Fallière's [Windows Anti-Debug reference](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-anti-debug-reference)
- OpenRCE's [Anti Reverse Engineering Techniques Database](http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/anti_reversing)
- Daniel Plohmann's [AntiRE](https://bitbucket.org/fkie_cd_dare/simplifire.antire)
- Rodrigo Branco's [Scientific but Not Academical Overview of Malware Anti-Debugging, Anti-Disassembly and Anti-
  VM Technologies](http://research.dissect.pe/docs/blackhat2012-paper.pdf)
- Mark Vincent Yason's [Art Of Unpacking](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-usa-07/Yason/Whitepaper/bh-usa-07-yason-WP.pdf)

Comment: This is a very good list.  I included it in the [anti-debug tag wiki](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/anti-debug/info), where this kind of information is better suited.

Comment: I see - will do it next time.