# Anti-dumping techniques

Tags: ida, anti-debugging, anti-dumping

After handing on some crackmes using packed codes, I am now curious about `anti-dumping techniques`. For the crackmes I have encoutered, my method is as follows: after the program unpacks itself, I take a memory snapshot (using IDA), then analysis the unpacked code (this approach has been proposed also by Igor in the answer of [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-analyze-a-potentially-harmful-binary-safely)).

Since these crackmes are not sophisticated enough, this method works. But I am quite sure that there are more sophisticated techniques can bypass this method. The most detail document I can find is [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30815/An-Anti-Reverse-Engineering-Guide#AntiDumping), however the discussed techiques are all about inserting (e.g. Nanomites) special codes into original ones or changing them completely (e.g. VMProtect, Code Virtualizer); or some other tricks to fool debuggers/disassemblers.

So my question is: are there existing techniques that prevent us from understanding the program by taking memory snapshot, while they do not change the original codes?

NB1. I have found a very close question and answer [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72/unpacking-binaries)

Comment: Modern protectors do not unpack/decrypt the code completely. Decryption is done as and when necessary. Sometimes a code block is re-encrypted after execution. Thus you never reach a point where the entire code has been decrypted and memory snapshots/dumping aren't effective.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ExtremeCoders, I know about "dynamic obfuscation" using just-in-time code generation and an implementation by Tigress. But this kind of self-modifying code may not "cruel" enough. Are there some "underground techniques" and real world samples?

Comment: I hear only about the approach of Armadillo but I have not try it.

Comment: Armadillo with its CopyMem II should be a good reference.

Comment: See [What are good Windows anti-debug references?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/what-are-good-windows-anti-debug-references)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JasonGeffner, consuming the articles in your links is not easy. I will start with them.